# Java EE and Java ME application integration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

I am a final year student, and working for my final year project. I need help, because I'm stuck with a problem. Actually, I made a website using Java EE with an Oracle database.

Now, in my project, there is one more module checking status using a mobile application, which I have made using Java ME and that is installed on a mobile. Now, I want to insert data into the Oracle database by using this mobile application. Whatever value I'll enter using the mobile needs to be entered into the database, which is running on localhost.

But, I don't have any idea how to integrate these two technology (Java EE + Java ME) and interact on localhost. I am using NetBeans 6.8 IDE for developing the project. Any toolkit or any tutorial to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Netbeans you can do it very easy with SOAP web services. Create an stateless EJB and mark its methods as web service methods, then run it on your machine. Once you have a web service running you can easily create web service stubs on your Java ME application by using Netbeans wizard, just point it the right wsdl file generated for you when you were creating ejb web service endpoint.
To access the web service from your mobile you would have to actually expose it to the outside world. You can do that if you'll find out your external IP address and properly configure your router at home. Once you can access your web service using your external IP you can try to regenerate the stubs on your mobile app, deploy it to the real device and check if its working.

If you don't want to bother with accessing your web service from outside world you can always test your Java ME application on your emulator, in that case your emulator will recognize 'localhost' address where you've deployed your app.

It should be enough to show that your project is working on the emulator but at the same time prove that you know whats happening and why you did it this way and not with the specifed external IP.

Answer (score 2):

Consider JSR 172 J2ME Web Services API. Some tutorials you might take a look at:
- [Introduction to J2ME Web Services](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/) at developers.sun.com
- [Web Services APIs for J2ME](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-jsr/) at IBM developerworks (same author btw)

Also you can check [jsr172 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr172/info) and search the web for something like "JSR 172 tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a web front end, or just use pure servlets in the Java EE part, and in the Java ME part you would use the internet/HTTP library to POST or GET data to/from the Java EE one.

In short, use HTTP since Java EE has good internet/http API. The Java EE one has to "listen" using servlets and perform the action on the db based on the http request data. If you dont like to use servlets and http another option is to use Web services, I believe Java ME has an API for web services.

On the Java ME side you would use the `HttpConnection` class to setup a connection and perform request/response.

Look into if you could use JMS, if there is a Java ME API for talking JMS.